# camaro is throwing error in Node

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install, node-modules

Installed camaro in ubuntu 12.04

```
npm install camaro
```

This line is throwing error:

```
const transform = require('camaro')
```

Getting following error in the console while running the app.

```
module.js:670
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /data/workspace/project_a/node_modules/camaro/lib/binding/camaro.node)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:670:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/data/workspace/project_a/node_modules/camaro/index.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
```

Comment: 12 is a bit old. Can you try it on the latest Ubuntu.